# Unable to instantiate an object using parameterized Constructor in java

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

**This is the class I want to Instantiate:**

```
public class GoogleSheetsAPI {

String spreadsheetId;
Sheets service;
String credentialsFile;

public void GoogleSheetsAPI() {
}

public void GoogleSheetsAPI(String spreadsheetId, String credentialsFile) throws Exception {
    this.spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId;
    this.credentialsFile = credentialsFile;
    service = getSheetsService();
}
```

}

**This is how I am creating an object of class** `GoogleSheetsAPI`

```
GoogleSheetsAPI googleSheetsAPI = new GoogleSheetsAPI(spreadsheetId, credentiialsFile);
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any parameterized code here; do you understand what that word means? Removed tag.

Comment: @Abhijit What do you call **spreadsheetId, credentiialsFile** ?

Comment: Formal parameters. https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap34A/ch34A_3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor must not have `void`, it should be:

```
public GoogleSheetsAPI(String spreadsheetId, String credentialsFile) throws Exception {
    this.spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId;
    this.credentialsFile = credentialsFile;
    service = getSheetsService();
}
```

Comment: This is the mistake I had done. Thank you Damian :) No void for Constructors.

Answer (score 0):

the constructor does not have any return type... because is a special method, if you define own constructor then not define empty constructor because jvm provide default...

Answer (score -1):

Class.newInstance invokes the no-arg constructor

```
Class<?> cl = Class.forName("javax.swing.JLabel");
Constructor<?> cons = cl.getConstructor(String.class);
```

Object o = cons.newInstance("JLabel");

to invoke a different constructor, you need to use the reflection package (java.lang.reflect).